# Installing cygwin with compilers and development packages

Tags: windows, cygwin, compilation, kannel

I need to compile kannel for windows and I installed cygwin. It says I don't have compilers to compile with cygwin. How do I resolve this ? Is there any full-featured cygwin image available anywhere on the internet ?

Please help. SOS!

I'm following **[this](http://saurabhsachdeva.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/kannel-installation-on-windows/)** tutorial to compile kannel with cygwin.

- **http://saurabhsachdeva.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/kannel-installation-on-windows/**

Comment: Double-posting on ServerFault doesn't help: http://serverfault.com/questions/96344/how-do-i-install-kannel-on-windows

Comment: Ha ha, you spotted budy. but I really need help. I'm windows guy with wizards. But I'll remove from there ethically.

Comment: Posting spam links is also not going to help

Comment: I regret I didnt notice this. I have updated the link with correct reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Kannel is written in C, so you probably just need to install `make`, `gcc`, and so on; these aren't included in the base Cygwin install, so you need to re-run the installer and make sure you select those packages.  See the [Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.setup.what-packages).

Comment: @this.__curious_geek: This is what the sentence "Remember you have to install the development tools required to compile kannel." means under your provided link.

Answer (score -1):

As kannel is built with C, you need a C compiler. In my case, I have Visual Studio 2010, which has a built in C compiler. Just Google for "C compiler"; you can get many Open Source ones for free.